# CREATE OPERATOR public.=> Error on PostgreSQL 9.4.20 backup to PostgreSQL 11.1 Restore

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I'm backing up a large database from PostgreSQL 9.4.20 and restoring it to PostgreSQL 11.1.

I'm getting this error:

```
syntax error at or near "=>"
```

It stems from this code:

```
--
-- Name: =>; Type: OPERATOR; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE OPERATOR public.=> (
    FUNCTION = public.tconvert,
    LEFTARG = text,
    RIGHTARG = text
);
```

Can this be safely ignored? If not, how can it be prevented or fixed?

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the [release notes for 9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-9-5.html):

> Allow `=>` to specify named parameters in function calls (Pavel Stehule)
>
> Previously only `:=` could be used. This requires removing the possibility for `=>` to be a user-defined operator. Creation of user-defined `=>` operators has been issuing warnings since PostgreSQL 9.0.

Your best way forward is to rename the operator *before* you migrate.

Comment: Thanks! I'll just rename it and hopefully the built-in functionality does what is needed when called.